# How to design a content moderation system for a time-sensitive use case?

Tags: design-ethics, moderation

I am designing a publicly accessible site, where any public user can make a post and have it appear on the site. Think of it like a public Facebook wall or an imageboard. This is for a specific use case which  I unfortunately don't want to disclose, but there is an element of **time-sensitivity**; *i.e. if the post only appears 2 hours later, it is too late.* To use an analogy, imagine if the fire department only picked up calls 2 hours later.

Obviously such a board would be ripe for abuse; people spamming, posting inappropriate content etc. Most sites deal with it by having moderators manually approve posts or members (think private Facebook groups) before they are posted online. On top of having a bunch of safeguards; capchas, automatic detection of inappropriate content etc., requiring users to create an account tied to their phone number with verification etc...

What is the best way to design this? **Having the post be up ASAP is important. Part of that includes making the user jump through as few hoops as possible** e.g. waiting for an account verification message. There are similar cases where the moderator approved the post after 2-3 hours, which was too late for the use case.

What I intend to do is, let the post go through first no matter what, and then do manual removal of post if it violates policy. Perhaps have some community 'Report Abuse' button ala 4chan to hide blatantly offensive posts.

Are there examples where this is done well?

Answer (score 1):

The default mode of operation of any forum, blog or social media website works for your use case - have some heuristics which filter out spam initially (for many sites, this would be Akismet), and put everything which isn't blatant spam online immediately. Users can then report any content which slipped through the filters and bring it to moderator attention.

Accounts and phone verification and such are usual, but not required (most blogs let you comment without an account).